# Manipulating Shared Strings Table when saving OpenXML document

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, vba

I am trying to create an Excel 2010 workbook using Entity Framework data (EF isn't the issue).  I'm more or less following code in:  [CodeProject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97307/Using-C-and-Open-XML-SDK-2-0-for-Microsoft-Office)

The code that creates a text cell in the link above has all text created as Inline Strings.  In order to follow best practices (at least as far as I understand OpenXML) I want to change this to use the Shared Strings table and so I'm following code found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830(v=office.14).aspx) to help.

To do this, I grab the Shared strings table from the workbook, add my string to it and then save the table. My code:

```
private static int InsertSharedStringItem(WorkbookPart wbPart, string value)
{
  int index = 0;
  bool found = false;
  var stringTablePart = wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();

  if (stringTablePart == null)
  {
    // Create it.
    stringTablePart = wbPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
  }

  var stringTable = stringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
  if (stringTable == null)
  {
    stringTable = new SharedStringTable();
  }

  foreach (SharedStringItem item in stringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>())
  {
    if (item.InnerText == value)
    {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
    index += 1;
  }
```

```
  if (!found)
  {
    stringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new Text(value)));
    stringTable.Save();
  }
```

```
  return index;
}
```

I've highlighted (and apparently separated) the problem area)

Unfortunately I get an `InvalidOperationException:  Cannot save DOM tree since this element is not associated with an OpenXmlPart` on the stringTable.Save(); line

I have tried to correct this by changing the if(!found) block to:

```
if (!found)
{
    stringTable.AppendChild(new SharedStringItem(new Text(value)));
    wbPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable = stringTable;
    stringtable.Save();
}
```

When the code hits the new line it returns an `UnhandledArgument Exception:  Cannot set the given root element to this part. The given part root element has already been associated with another OpenXmlPart.`

At this point, I'm confused as to whether or not my `stringtable` is associated with an OpenXmlPart or not.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong or maybe point out a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

When you add the SharedStringTablePart, immediately initialise the SharedStringTable associated with the part. Then you don't check for nullity on the SharedStringTable object. Try this:

```
if (stringTablePart == null)
{
    // Create it.
    stringTablePart = wbPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
    stringTablePart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();
}

var stringTable = stringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
//if (stringTable == null)
//{
//    stringTable = new SharedStringTable();
//}
```

I hope that fragment is good enough for you to identify the part in your function. If the SharedStringTablePart is not null, it will already have a SharedStringTable object in it. If it's null, then... well, create both at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not useful for the original poster, but in case anyone else stumbles across this. Microsoft's example has a template excel file they use to modify. This answer is for creating an excel document from scratch. Hope this helps someone.

Try adding the `SharedStringTablePart` and `SharedStringTable` when creating and first saving the document. I'm creating a file and place it in the temp folder, then reopen the file to modify.

```
public string CreateSpreadsheet()
 {
    string filepath = Path.GetTempFileName();
    filepath = filepath.Replace(".tmp", ".xlsx");
    // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
    // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.
    Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);


    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();
    workbookpart.Workbook.Save();


    **WorkbookPart wbPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    var stringTablePart = wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (stringTablePart == null)
    {
      // Create it.
      stringTablePart = wbPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
    }
    stringTablePart.SharedStringTable = new SharedStringTable();**

    // Close the document.
    spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    return filepath;
    }
```